# Drop-Down Lists from laravelcollective?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I use dropdownlist from laravelcollective. I am wondering how I can use (Selected Default) with this if I fetch data from a database. Here follows my source code:

```
{!! Form::select('port',$ports,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

The selected default that I want is for example (Select Port).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all create a list in your controller and use as a first element the "Please select a port" text with empty value:

```
$ports =['' => 'Please Select a port'] + Port::lists('shortName','id')->toArray();
```

After you pass it to the view use it like this:

```
{!! Form::select('port_id',$ports,null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct is to use attribute `placeholder` in dropdown.

```
{!! Form::select('port', $ports, null, ['placeholder' => 'Select a Port', 'class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```